# Remove the metadata/EXIF data, GPS location from the images I select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to capture images using cordovaCamera and imagePicker then remove the EXIF data and create a copy of the image in the local app folder after the EXIF is removed. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.